# Whats the difference between base_frame and base_link?

Tags: ros, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to map a model(urdf) to my hector slam project which seems to have base_frame.  I don't have any base_link?

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link
```

CFailure at 1485981006.541937303 Exception thrown:"base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.  The current list of frames is: Frame laser exists with parent base_frame. Frame base_frame exists with parent map. Frame scanmatcher_frame exists with parent map.

If I change my URDF from base_link to base_frame, I have less errors in RVIZ but the wheels are not connected to the robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253542/whats-the-difference-between-base_frame-and-base_link?/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-02-01**:
`base_frame` is a ROS parameter. `base_link` is a common value of the `base_frame` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no difference, both of them are the parameters used too mention the  base frame of the tf tree. In order to approach your scenario, change the base frame name in URDF to base_link else run the tf node as below

```
$rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_frame
```

---

Originally posted by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) with karma: 173 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-01**:
If I update my URDF file to base_frame, my wheels are not attached